# Whenever I am removing the already existing text from the button tag or adding a txt to an empty button tag, the button element's position is changing

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, tic-tac-toe

So, I have this code written in react for a simple tic tac toe game where i am creating the grid squares using 9 button tags.

My issue is that whenever i am removing the X / O (these are x and o from the tic tac toe game) from a button, that button element is changing it's position.

P.S. Whenever a button (or square) is clicked , a 'X' is embedded inside that button tag.

```
> App.js

import './App.css';

function App() {

  const onClickHandler = (event) => {
    const elemclicked = event.target;
    elemclicked.innerText = 'X';
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main className="main-content">
            <div className="game">
                <div className="board-row row1">
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square b-top-0 b-left-0"></button>
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square b-top-0"></button>
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square b-top-0 b-right-0"></button>
                </div>
                <div className="board-row row2">
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square b-left-0"></button>
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square"></button>
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square b-right-0"></button>
                </div>
                <div className="board-row row3">
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square b-bottom-0 b-left-0"></button>
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square b-bottom-0"></button>
                    <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="square b-bottom-0 b-right-0"></button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className="restart-btn"></div>
            <div className="history"></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
> CSS

.b-top-0{
  border-top: 0;
}

.b-left-0{
  border-left: 0;
}

.b-bottom-0{
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.b-right-0{
  border-right: 0;
}

.square{
  background-color: rgb(8, 8, 37);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: white;
}

.main-content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.game{
  display: inline-block;
  /* margin: 0 10px; */
}
```

Adding some images for reference :
[When all the button tags are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhV0P.png)
[After clicking any button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmvOo.png)

I was hoping that upon clicking the button, a 'X' would simply be embedded in that button tag with no change in layout but the layout is getting disfigured.